# Result of 'git diff' without additional parameters?

Tags: git, diff

I checked the names of changed files using git diff master --name-only, and recieved a result of my changes similar to the following:

```
really/long/path/to/file.java
really/long/path/to/fileNumber2.java    
really/long/path/to/fileNumber3.java
really/long/path/to/fileNumber4.java
```

After this, I ran `git diff` without any extra parameters and got a large list of changes in the codebase that were not from those files. My question is, **what comparison does a simple `git diff` make?**

My guess is: it shows the difference between the latest and previous commits, but a `man git-diff` and a bit of reading didn't make things clearer for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained by [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#git-diff-emgitdiffem--options--ltpathgt82308203), just calling `git diff` without specifying any revision will show you the changes relative to the index, i.e. all pending changes that appear in the *“Changes not staged for commit”* list when running `git status`.

> **`git diff [--options] [--] [<path>…​]`**
>
> This form is to view the changes you made relative to the index (staging area for the next commit). In other words, the differences are what you *could* tell Git to further add to the index but you still haven’t. You can stage these changes by using [git-add[1]](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add).

Comment: So to summarize: changes that are not yet staged. Thanks for the help!